# X Window opened from screen

Tags: xorg, gnu-screen, ssh-tunneling

Bit of an oddish one, if I've opened an X window over SSH in a screen session will it reopen when screen is reattached? I've been able to detach and the process stays running fine, with the X window continuing to update with me logged onto the server but I'm just curious if I'll be able to detach and logoff, then reattach and bring the window back.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you logged into a remote system with SSH with X forwarding turned on, and then started up an X application and sent it to the background.  If you log off completely, the SSH tunnel that provides the X forwarding feature will also close, and the X app will be terminated.  However, most likely what will happen when you try to log off is that the SSH session will remain open until the X application exits.  The screen session is inconsequential at this point.

Interestingly enough, there appears to be some work on being able to [save and restore X sessions](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) like screen does with terminal sessions.

Comment: +1 for xpra, because it is awesome. I think it'd be better to call it "a separate project", because it's neither an enhancement to `screen` nor to the X protocol itself.

Comment: Ah thank you, well that's a bit of a pain, I was hoping having it running under screen would keep the process live and just have the X window 'hidden' until reattach.